# Apache Airflow -- custom class to be used in multiple places

Tags: python, airflow

I'm using Airflow 1.10.2. And I'm trying to define a custom module which would contain general functionality which can be used in multiple dags as well as operators.

A specific example can be an `enum`. I want to use it within a custom operator (to modify its behaviour). But I also want to use it within a `dag` definition where it can be used as a parameter.

This is my current hierarchy

```
airflow_home
 | - dags/
      - __init__.py
      - my_dag.py
 | - plugins/
      - operators/
         - __init__.py
         - my_operator.py
      - common/
             - __init__.py
             - my_enum.py
```

Let's say I want define an enum (in `my_enum.py` module):

```py
class MyEnum(Enum):
   OPTION_1 = 1
   OPTION_2 = 2
```

It is imported to the operator (in `my_operator.py`) as:

```py
from common.my_enum import MyEnum
```

And in to the dag (in `my_dag.py`) the same way:

```py
from common.my_enum import MyEnum
```

Strangely(?), this works for me. However, I'm very uncertain whether this is the correct way of doing such thing. I was told by a colleague that he tried to do this in the past (possibly on older version of Airflow) and it was not working ("broken dag" when airflow started). Therefore, I'm afraid it might not be (might stop) working in the future or in specific conditions, as it is neither an operator, nor a sensor etc.

I didn't find any guidelines on how to separate shared behaviour. I find the airflow import system quite complicated and not very straight forward. My ideal solution would be to move the module `common` on the same level as `dags` and `operators`.

Also I'm not very sure about how to interpret this sentence from the docs: `The python modules in the plugins folder get imported, and hooks, operators, sensors, macros, executors and web views get integrated to Airflow’s main collections and become available for use.` Does it mean that my approach is correct, because any python module in `plugins/` gets imported?

Is this a good way to achieve my goal, or is there a better solution?

Thank you for your advice

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hakish way of doing it.

Proper way would be first to create a `hook` and than `operator` which will use this hook. For simpler case as one below you don't even need to call hook in operator.

#1. **Placing**

```
<PROJECT NAME>/<PLUGINS_FOLDER>/<PLUGIN NAME>/__init__.py
<PROJECT NAME>/<PLUGINS_FOLDER>/<PLUGIN NAME>/<some_new>_hook.py
<PROJECT NAME>/<PLUGINS_FOLDER>/<PLUGIN NAME>/<some_new>_operator.py
```

For real case scenario that would look like this:

```
CRMProject/crm_plugin/__init__.py
CRMProject/crm_plugin/crm_hook.py
CRMProject/crm_plugin/customer_operator.py
```

#2. **Code**

Sample code of `CRMProject/crm_plugin/__init__.py`:

```
# CRMProject/crm_plugin/__init__.py
from airflow.plugins_manager import AirflowPlugin
from crm_plugin.crm_hook import CrmHook
from crm_plugin.customer_operator import CreateCustomerOperator, DeleteCustomerOperator, UpdateCustomerOperator


class AirflowCrmPlugin(AirflowPlugin):
    name = "crm_plugin"  # does not need to match the package name
    operators = [CreateCustomerOperator, DeleteCustomerOperator, UpdateCustomerOperator]
    sensors = []
    hooks = [CrmHook]
    executors = []
    macros = []
    admin_views = []
    flask_blueprints = []
    menu_links = []
    appbuilder_views = []
    appbuilder_menu_items = []
    global_operator_extra_links = []
    operator_extra_links = []
```

Sample code for hook class - `CRMProject/crm_plugin/crm_hook.py`. Don't ever call it directly from system\API. Use Operator for that (see below).

```
from airflow.hooks.base_hook import BaseHook
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from crm_sdk import crm_api  # import external libraries to interact with target system


class CrmHook(BaseHook):
    """
    Hook to interact with the ACME CRM System.
    """

    def __init__(self, ...):
        # your code goes here

    def insert_object(self, ...):
        """
        Insert an object into the CRM system
        """
        # your code goes here

    def update_object(self, ...):
        """
        Update an object into the CRM system
        """
        # your code goes here

    def delete_object(self, ...):
        """
        Delete an object into the CRM system
        """
        # your code goes here

    def extract_object(self, ...):
        """
        Extract an object into the CRM system
        """
        # your code goes here
```

Sample code for Operator (`CRMProject/crm_plugin/customer_operator.py`) which you will use in DAGs. Operators require that you implement an execute method. This is the entry point into your operator for Airflow and it is called when the task in your DAG executes.
The `apply_defaults` decorator wraps the `__init__` method of the class which applies the DAG defaults, set in your DAG script, to the task instance of your operator at run time.

There are also two important class attributes that we can set. These are `templated_fields` and `template_ext`. These two attributes are iterables that should contain the string values for the fields and/or file extensions that will allow templating with the jinja templating support in Airflow.

```
from airflow.exceptions import AirflowException
from airflow.operators import BaseOperator
from airflow.utils.decorators import apply_defauls

from crm_plugin.crm_hook import CrmHook


class CreateCustomerOperator(BaseOperator):
    """
    This operator creates a new customer in the ACME CRM System.
    """
    template_fields = ['first_contact_date', 'bulk_file']
    template_ext = ['.csv']

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, first_contact_date, bulk_file, ...):
        # your code goes here

    def _customer_exist(self, ...):
        """
        Helper method to check if a customer exist. Raises an exception if it does.
        """
        # your code goes here

    def execute(self, context):
        """
        Create a new customer in the CRM system.
        """
        # your code goes here
```

You can create as many methods in your class as you need in order to simplify you execute method. The same principles for good class design still counts here.

#3. **Deploying and using your plugin**

Once you have completed work on your plugin all that is left for you to do is to copy your `<PLUGIN NAME>` package folder to the Airflow plugins folder. Airflow will pick the plugin up and it will become available to your DAGs.
If we copied the simple CRM plugin to our `plugins_folder` the folder structure would look like this.

```
<plugins_folder>/crm_plugin/__init__.py
<plugins_folder>/crm_plugin/crm_hook.py
<plugins_folder>/crm_plugin/customer_operator.py
```

In order to use your new plugin you will simply import your Operators and Hooks using the following statements.

```
from airflow.hooks.crm_plugin import CrmHook
from airflow.operators.crm_plugin import CreateCustomerOperator, DeleteCustomerOperator, UpdateCustomerOperator
```

[Source](https://pybit.es/introduction-airflow.html)

Comment: This answer is nice, but it doesn't really answer the question of where to place the enum, so that both the operator and the DAGs can use it. Same goes e.g. for smaller utility functions that don't fit into a custom operator.